# How do you use Leafletjs to show popups on a non-map image?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I'm using the `CRS.Simple` class of Leaflet js library. Here is the [example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) from their documentation.

I'm trying to use the library to have panning, scrolling, zooming, and popups on a very large (9600x7200 pixel) image. The popups are all based on the coordinate location in pixels based on the original size of the image.

It is rendering fine, but the actual popup is not in the place I would expect it. Here is my code:

```
  var map = L.map("map", {
    maxZoom: 5,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
  });
  var bounds = [
    [0, 0],
    [112.5, 150]
  ];
  var image = L.imageOverlay("image-url", bounds).addTo(map);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  map.setView([84, 116.64], 5);

  var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng([84, 116.64])
    .setContent("pop up test.")
    .openOn(map);
```

In the documentation it said to not use the whole pixel value for the bounds, so I divided everything by 64. I would expect the `setView()` and `popup()` to be somewhere in the bottom-right quadrent when it renders, but it is actually in the top-right. I think I just don't have my coordinates setup correctly.

Comment: A few clarifications are needed. How does your image look like? What's the meaning of your coordinate system? Do you expect the Y (vertical) coordinate to increase when going up (cartesian coordinates) or when going down (screen coordinates)?

Comment: @IvanSanchez The coordinate system has no meaning to me other than putting pins on top of a location. I have the x,y pixel (screen) coordinates of specific locations on the image but I don't think they're working when i try to convert in leaflet.